# gnuplot: extract x-values from string in data

Tags: gnuplot

My data files look like this:

```
c0e0100.dat 0.234
c0e0200.dat 0.857
...
c0e1200.dat 0.003
```

I would like to extract the x-values from the 4th to 7th character of the filenames in the first column.
I tried the following user function:

```
str2num(s)=(s[4:7]+0.0)
```

and then:

```
plot 'file' using (str2num($1)):($2)
```

but this gives:

```
internal error: substring range operator applied to non-STRING type
```

I also tried:

```
plot 'file' using (str2num(stringcolumn($1))):($2)
```

but got the same result.

Is there a way of doing this in gnuplot without running the data through external tools first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `$1` is a short cut for `column(1)`, so using `$1` already gives you the numerical representation of the respective column. To get the string value, use `stringcolumn(1)` (without `$`!), or `strcol(1)`:

```
str2num(s)=(s[4:7]+0.0)
plot 'file ' using (str2num(strcol(1))):2
```

Comment: When I try this  I get the following error message: `Non-numeric string found where a numeric expression was expected'

Comment: Works fine for me on Linux with version 5.0, 4.6.4 and 4.2.6. I guess you are working on Windows. Then you should get the same error if you just do `print str2num("c0e0100.dat")`.

Comment: Sorry, your answer is correct and works. I have a header row in my file (not shown in the example). I needed to add 'skip 1' to the plot command to make it work. Thanks!